# how can i add binding.xml to Dynamically generated java sources (without xjc)

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb, xjc

my code is:

```
import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;

import com.sun.tools.xjc.api.S2JJAXBModel;

import com.sun.tools.xjc.api.SchemaCompiler;

import com.sun.tools.xjc.api.XJC;

public class JAXCodeGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String outputDirectory = "d:/src/";

            // Setup schema compiler
            SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
            sc.forcePackageName("com.xyz.schema");

            // Setup SAX InputSource
            File schemaFile = new File("Item.xsd");
            InputSource is = new InputSource(schemaFile.toURI().toString());
          //  is.setSystemId(schemaFile.getAbsolutePath());

            // Parse & build
            sc.parseSchema(is);
            S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();
            JCodeModel jCodeModel = model.generateCode(null, null);
            jCodeModel.build(new File(outputDirectory));

    }
}
```

And my question is how can i add binding.xml through code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this looks to me as if you were simply trying to invoke xjc from a Java program. (Why not from the command line, or maven, or...???)

However, whatever system you are on, you might invoke xjc from Java using ProcessBuilder, where you can specify all required parameters and options, including `-b pathname' for specifying a binding file.

Alternatively, you could insert all binding specs in the XML schema file.

**Later**

**Warning: getOption is not guranteed to remain stable with future releases of xjc** but there's no other way. com.sun.tools.xjc.api is not really meant to be used in applications.

```
SchemaCompiler sc = ...;

File bindings = new File(...);
sc.getOptions().addBindFile( bindings );
```

You can also use the command line parser, which could simplify things if you have multiple options.

```
String[] args = ...; // options and parameters as they appear on a command line
int done = 0;
while( done < args.length ){
    int eaten = 0;
    try {
        eaten = sc.getOptions().parseArgument( args, done );
    } catch( com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException bcle ){
        // handle the exception
    } finally {
        done += eaten;
    }
    if( eaten == 0 ) break;  // not recognized, can't continue, abort
}
```

Comment: Thank... but for command line you have to set classpath else you have to specify full path of xjc. So i want platform independent code.

Comment: @Sandippatil JAVA_HOME can be expected to point to the directory tree where Java lives. And I'm sure you know how to '/' or '\' ;-) And it is NOT true that you have to set classpath for running xjc without an absolute pathname.

Comment: @Sandippatil I've added a couple of calls to set the -b option, and for options in general. Take care, this is *not guaranteed to remain stable* in future JAXB/xjc releases.

Comment: its compile but not give proper output.. it gives output like i never used binding.xml..

Comment: Works for me, although it's very easy to introduce an error. Make sure to have a set of files you can compile using xjc from the command line. Or add an error listener to the SchemaCompiler.